# How Can I Convert String to List in Apache Spark and write database(JSON )?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my spark application I listen Kafka topic and process data then write the Cassandra.
The json data coming to Kafka is as follows.

```
"categories":[
  {
     "name":"Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry",
     "types":"ROOT",
     "id":"fashion_display_on_website",
     "rank":324064
  },
  {
     "name":"Men's Wool Jackets & Coats",
     "types":"SUB",
     "id":"2476613011",
     "rank":69
  },
  {
     "name":"Women's Coats, Jackets & Vests",
     "types":"SUB",
     "id":"1044646",
     "rank":1919
  }
]
```

The schema I use is as follows.

```
|-- categories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rank: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- types: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

In my application ı filter 'SUB' types like this.

```
val infoDF_all1 = infoDF
      .select(
        explode(expr("filter(categories, x -> x.types=='SUB')")).alias("sub_category"),
        expr("filter(categories, x -> x.types=='ROOT')").alias("main_category")


val infoDF_all2 = infoDF_all1
      .withColumn("sub_category_ids", col("sub_category.id"))
      .withColumn("sub_category", col("sub_category.name"))
```

That way it only writes to the last sub_category database.

```
+---------------------------------+----------------+
|sub_category                     |sub_category_ids|
+---------------------------------+----------------+
|Women's Coats, Jackets & Vests   |2476613011      |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

**I want both sub_category and sub_category_ids like this way to writes**:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+
|sub_category                     |sub_category_ids          |          
+---------------------------------+--------------------------|
|["Women's Coats, Jackets & Vests",|["1044646","2476613011"] |
|  "Men''s Wool Jackets & Coats"]  |                         |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

The data types in the table I will write are as follows:

sub_category --> list[text]

sub_category_ids --> list[text]

Comment: Why filter by `x.types=='ROOT'`  if you never use the main category column? There's no clear relationship of categories between roots and subdepartment, and if there were, I think you'd want a recursive schema or the parent department id in each sub record

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually there is more column in table(includes main column).I just wanted to show it as I was having trouble with the sub_category and sub_category_ids columns.